# Vemco Acoustic Telemetry Data (vrl files) in R

Tags: r

Does anyone know a good way to read .vrl files from Vemco acoustic telemetry receivers directly into r as an object. Converting .vrl files to .csv files in the program VUE prior to analyzing the data in r seems like a waste of time if there is a way to bring them in directly. My internet searches have not turned up anything that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way using glatos to convert all .vrl files to .csv and then reading the .csv files in and binding them.

glatos has to be installed from github.
Convert all .vrl files to .csv files using `vrl2csv`. The help page has info on finding the path for vueExePath

`library(glatos)`

`vrl2csv(vrl = "VRLFileInput",outDir = "VRLFilesToCSV", vueExePath = "C:/Program Files (x86)/VEMCO/VUE")`

The following will pull in all .csv files in the output folder from `vrl2csv` and rbind them together. I had to add the `paste0` function to create the full file path for each .csv in the list.
`library(data.table)`

`AllDetections <-  do.call(rbind, lapply(paste0("VRLFilesToCSV/", list.files(path = "VRLFilesToCSV")), read.csv))`

Comment: note that glatos::vrl2csv returns a character vector with the full path to csv files, so you can skip the paste0 if you assign that vrl2csv call to an object. e.g., `csv_files <- vrl2csv(...`

Comment: Good point @ChrisHolbrook that helps to simplify this a bit further.